# Android 34 - foreground location service started from background

Tags: android, foreground-service

My App is starting a foreground location service which starts from background from an Activity Transition event.

This functionality stopped working when targetSdk
is updated to 34

The App has background location permission and unrestricted battery usage.

The foreground service type and permission added to manifest and the parameter is passed to “startForeground” function

According to Android docs (https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services#wiu-restrictions)
It should be working but I am still getting the
"Foreground service started from background can not have location/camera/microphone access”
Message in the log

What am I missing?